# Dynamics CRM JavaScript Average

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I have three (3) Decimal Fields on a single record.  I need to add an additional Decimal field that will produce an Average of those values.  The problem is I do not know how to account for a record with a missing value.  If there are only 2 values present on the record, I need the JavaScript to average the 2 values and ignore the NULL value of the third Decimal field.

This function would then run onChange of those three decimal fields.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function average(array) {
  var averageArray=array.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
    return [accumulator[0]+currentValue, accumulator[1]+(currentValue!=null)];
  }, [0,0]);
  return averageArray[0]/averageArray[1];
}

console.log(average([12, null])); // 12
console.log(average([12, null, 14])); // 13
console.log(average([12, null, null, null, 14, 16])); // 14
```

And in "older" javascript:

```js
function average(array) {
  var sum=0, count=0;
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]!=null) {
      sum+=array[i];
      count++;
    }
  }
  return sum/count;
}

console.log(average([12, null])); // 12
console.log(average([12, null, 14])); // 13
console.log(average([12, null, null, null, 14, 16])); // 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner average using ES6 features

```js
const avg = (arr) => arr
  // filter out falsy values (except 0) and not number strings
  .filter(i => i && +i || i == 0)
  // accumulate remaining values with Array.reduce
  .reduce((a, c, _, o) => a + +c / o.length, 0); 
     
console.log(avg([null, null, '','asd'])); // 0
console.log(avg([10, null, ])); // 10
console.log(avg([10, '0', null])); // 5
console.log(avg(['10', 12, '14'])) // 12
console.log(avg(['10', 11, 0])); // 7
```